# gcloud beta logging for trailing logs

Tags: shell, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I just found out about google new "gcloud beta logging" service.
The classic sample they show is something like this:

```
 gcloud beta logging write my-test-log "A simple entry"
```

But I would like to log every new entry in a specific log file. For example:

```
 tail -F My_Log_File.txt | grep  gcloud beta logging write my-test-log
```

What is the best practice for this operation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

`tail -F My_Log_File.txt | xargs gcloud beta logging write my-test-log`

Or you can use a logging agent to watch certain files and log them to the logging service:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation
http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail